# Bash: Assign command to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, output

Below I have an example which confuses me a bit, any help would be appreciated.

I bind a normal command line command (ls) to a new variable. If I echo it it the output is just the command (ls) but if I just use the variable without echo i get the result of the command but why?? Is it because $listdir gets translated to ls so I just get the output? And if I use the echo command it will be interpreted as a string?

```
router@test:~/scripting$ listdir=ls
router@test:~/scripting$ echo "$listdir"
ls

----- VS ----
router@test:~/scripting$ $listdir
basicLoop.sh         fileflood.sh .......
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is the behavior that you expect?

Comment: The `$listdir` gets expanded, and the first word (`ls` here, which is also the only word for this case) of the expansion  is interpreted as a command, and subsequent words, if any, as arguments.

Comment: Uh I think the only answer here is ***Yes***.  Not enough to post!

Answer (score 1):

When bash is interpreting the commands you feed to it, the first thing it will do is expand any expansions it is given. So when you give it `$listdir` by the time bash starts to execute the value it is given, all it knows is that it was given the value `ls`. It does not care where the value came from, only what the value is.

Lets look at the trace given after running `set -x`, which instructs bash to prints to `stderr` after expansion and before execution:

```sh
$> echo $listdir
+ echo ls
ls

$> $listdir
+ ls
file_0 file_1
```

As you can see, in the second line, bash will attempt to run the command `ls` just as if you have explicity called `ls` or even `/usr/bin/ls`

## Edit

Expansion isn't the first step in in shell evaluation, see @Gordon Davisson's comment for details

Comment: Correction: expanding variables isn't the first thing the shell does. Most importantly, it comes after the shell parses things like quotes and escapes, command delimiters (`;`, `&`, etc), and redirects (`>`, `<`, etc), so if you include one of those in a variable, it won't be recognized. So you can store *simple* commands in variables, but not complex ones. And it's generally considered a bad idea anyway; variables are for data, not executable code. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1):

By doing `listdir=ls` you literally assign a string "ls" to the `$listdir` variable. So if you run `echo $listdir` now it will just expand into `echo ls`, which (as you may have guessed) will just print "ls" onto a screen. If you want to store **a result** of a command into a variable you can wrap the command in ``` `` ``` or `$()` (eg. `listdir=$(ls)` or `` listdir=`ls` ``).

```
jarmusz@emacs~$ listdir=`ls`
jarmusz@emacs~$ echo "$listdir"
dls
docs
music
...
```

If you want to store just a name of the command and run it later you can do it like this:

```
jarmusz@emacs~$ listdir=ls
<some other commands...>
jarmusz@emacs~$ echo `$listdir`
dls docs music ...
```

In this example, `` echo `$listdir` `` will expand into `` echo `ls` `` and then into `echo dls docs music...`